# Фильтрация блоков по data атрибутам

Tags: jquery

```html
<select class="select select-type">
    <option value="1" data-sort="all">All</option>
    <option value="2" data-sort="pistol">Pistol</option>
    <option value="3" data-sort="riffle">Riffle</option>
    <option value="4" data-sort="smg">SMG</option>
</select>

<select class="select select-class">
    <option value="1" data-sort="all">Все</option>
    <option value="2" data-sort="Base Grade">Base Grade</option>
    <option value="3" data-sort="Extraordinary">Extraordinary</option>
    <option value="4" data-sort="Industrial Grade">Industrial Grade</option>
</select>

<ul id="items">
  <li data-type="pistol" data-class="Base Grade">Item 1</li>
  <li data-type="pistol" data-class="Base Grade">Item 2</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Extraordinary">Item 3</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Extraordinary">Item 4</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Industrial Grade">Item 5</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Industrial Grade">Item 6</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Industrial Grade">Item 7</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Extraordinary">Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Есть 2 `select` (может быть и больше), как реализовать фильтрацию по значениям из селектов по Data атрибутам.

Например если в первом `select` выбран параметр `SMG` то показываются элементы с `item 3, item 7, item 8`(остальные скрываются), и если указать во втором селекте например параметр `Extraordinary`, то показываются только `item 4, item 8`

Comment: Вы сортировку с фильтрацией не перепутали?

Comment: извиняюсь, действительно перепутал. Исправил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".select-type, .select-class").change(function(){
  var dType = $(".select-type option:selected").data("sort");
  var dClass = $(".select-class option:selected").data("sort");
  $("#items li").each(function(){
    if ( (dType == "all" || dType == $(this).data("type")) &&
         (dClass == "all" || dClass == $(this).data("class")) ) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n9t6b0bf/1/

Comment: пардон, ошибся в названии `data` атрибута

Comment: как то без динамического числа фильтров не интересно :(

Comment: @teran это будет следующий вопрос

Comment: @teran , а что если с динамичным числом фильтров?

Comment: @igor , создать еще один вопрос? :)

Comment: @kiLLro Конечно.

Comment: @igor https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768512/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: @Igor так то написано было "2 и больше"