# Динамичное кол-во фильтров

Tags: jquery

```js
$(".select-type, .select-class").change(function(){
  var dType = $(".select-type option:selected").data("sort");
  var dClass = $(".select-class option:selected").data("sort");
  $("#items li").each(function(){
    if ( (dType == "all" || dType == $(this).data("type")) &&
         (dClass == "all" || dClass == $(this).data("class")) ) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select select-type">
    <option value="1" data-sort="all">All</option>
    <option value="2" data-sort="pistol">Pistol</option>
    <option value="3" data-sort="riffle">Riffle</option>
    <option value="4" data-sort="smg">SMG</option>
</select>

<select class="select select-class">
    <option value="1" data-sort="all">Все</option>
    <option value="2" data-sort="Base Grade">Base Grade</option>
    <option value="3" data-sort="Extraordinary">Extraordinary</option>
    <option value="4" data-sort="Industrial Grade">Industrial Grade</option>
</select>

<ul id="items">
  <li data-type="pistol" data-class="Base Grade">Item 1</li>
  <li data-type="pistol" data-class="Base Grade">Item 2</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Extraordinary">Item 3</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Extraordinary">Item 4</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Industrial Grade">Item 5</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Industrial Grade">Item 6</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Industrial Grade">Item 7</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Extraordinary">Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Требуется сделать динамичное количество фильтров. @igor призываю тебя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внес изменения в вашу верстку. добавил атрибут `data-filter` к селектам, содержит `type` или `class`, в общем, имя атрибута что фильтруем.

```js
$(".select").change(function(){

  // список доступных фильтров
  var filters = $(".select").toArray().map( function(v){
                    return $(v).data('filter');
                });
                
  // проверяем все элементы списка
  $("#items li").each(function(idx, li){
      var show = true;       // по умолчанию показываем
      
      // сверяем все data- атрибуты доступных фильтров
      $.each(filters, function(fIdx, fname){  
          // значение селекта фильтра    
          var fv = $(".select-" + fname + " :selected").data('sort');
                    
          if(fv == 'all') return true;
                  
          // сверяям значение селекта с дата-атрбутом
          if( $(li).data(fname) != fv){
              show = false;
              return false;
          } 
      });
      
      $(this).toggle(show);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select select-type" data-filter="type">
    <option value="all" data-sort="all">All</option>
    <option value="2" data-sort="pistol">Pistol</option>
    <option value="3" data-sort="riffle">Riffle</option>
    <option value="4" data-sort="smg">SMG</option>
</select>

<select class="select select-class" data-filter="class">
    <option value="all" data-sort="all">Все</option>
    <option value="2" data-sort="Base Grade">Base Grade</option>
    <option value="3" data-sort="Extraordinary">Extraordinary</option>
    <option value="4" data-sort="Industrial Grade">Industrial Grade</option>
</select>

<ul id="items">
  <li data-type="pistol" data-class="Base Grade">Item 1 (Pistol,Base Grad)</li>
  <li data-type="pistol" data-class="Base Grade">Item 2 (Pistol,Base Grad)</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Extraordinary">Item 3 (smg,Extraordinary)</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Extraordinary">Item 4 (riffle,Extraordinary)</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Industrial Grade">Item 5 (riffle,Industrial Grade)</li>
  <li data-type="riffle" data-class="Industrial Grade">Item 6 (riffle,Industrial Grade)</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Industrial Grade">Item 7 (smg,Industrial Grade)</li>
  <li data-type="smg" data-class="Extraordinary">Item 8 (smg,Extraordinary)</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Сортировку по цене(новый атрибут data-price) - (от большего к меньшему, и от меньшего к большему) - возможно при такой структуре сделать?

Comment: @kiLLro сортировка и фильтрация это разные вещи.

Comment: да я понимаю, возможно ли интегрировать сюда еще и сортировку?

Comment: @kiLLro в целом да, но это будет другая функция на js

Comment: Вы изменили значение атрибутов указав там значение селекторов, но нужен как раз таки текст.

Comment: @kiLLro вернул обратно

Answer (score 1):

```
function showItems(){
  var dType = $(".select-type option:selected").data("sort");
  var dClass = $(".select-class option:selected").data("sort");
  $("#items li").each(function(){
    if ( (dType == "all" || dType == $(this).data("type")) &&
         (dClass == "all" || dClass == $(this).data("class")) ) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}

$(".select-type").change(function(){
  var oldClass = $(".select-class").val();

  var allClasses = [
    { value: 1, filter: "all", text: "Все" },
    { value: 2, filter: "Base Grade", text: "Base Grade" },
    { value: 3, filter: "Extraordinary", text: "Extraordinary" },
    { value: 4, filter: "Industrial Grade", text: "Industrial Grade" }
  ];

  $(".select-class").empty();
  var dType = $(".select-type option:selected").data("sort");

  function addClassOption(filter) {
    var classItem = allClasses.find(function(item) { return item.filter == filter; });
    if (classItem) {
      $("<option></option>").attr("value", item.value).data("sort", item.filter).text(item.text).appendTo(".select-class");
    }
  }

  addClassOption("all");
  $("#items li").each(function(){
    if (dType == "all" || dType == $(this).data("type")) {
      addClassOption($(this).data("class"));
    }
  });

  $(".select-class").val(oldClass);

  showItems();
});

$(".select-class").change(function(){
  showItems();
});
```

*Update*

Я, вероятно, неправильно понял вопрос. Мне почему-то показалось, что речь идет о динамическом наборе опций в втором селекте, отражающем выбор в первом селекте.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n9t6b0bf/2/

Comment: @kiLLro https://jsfiddle.net/n9t6b0bf/3/